# Spring Boot - ignore property server.contextPath

Tags: java, spring, web

In my spring application.properties I've got property

```
server.contextPath=/my/context/path
```

But I need to setup controller that will handle this path:

```
http:/localhost:8888/
```

Is there any way to ignore server.contextPath property only in one controller?

Thanks

Comment: would  you describe a tittle more.?

Answer (score 1):

No.

While using one `DispatcherServlet` you could remove the `server.contextPath` property and annotate all your controllers (but one) with `@RequestMapping("/my/context/path")`

Another options is to work with two `DispatcherServlet`s. One mapped to `/*` containing the one controller and a second one mapped to `/my/context/path/*` containing all the other controllers.